# Make a border around a image for a profile picture using css/bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hey guys I am trying to put a border around this image for something like this:[border blue around picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBe07.png)  Here is the code that I had tried also I would like for it to be in the left corner of the page. Thanks for the help in advance. Here's a preview of the code I have right now:https://jsfiddle.net/7hdrhs2r/3/
HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
        <!-- Picture must be 600px X 600px-->
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-xs-6" id="picturebox">

      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Apple_logo_black.svg/600px-Apple_logo_black.svg.png" alt="profile pic" height="10%" width="10%"/>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#picturebox{
       border-color:midnightblue;
        margin: 0 auto;
     border:10px solid #ccc;
     border-right: 200%;
         padding:20px 60px 0px 2px ;
         height: 100%
        width:50%;
        background-color:lightblue;
    }
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Include a JSfiddle, first of all.

Comment: Put your css here. See if you can fix any errors. https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7hdrhs2r/3/

Comment: Add that jsfiddle to the post, so everyone can see it. Is it what you want, or what you have as of now?

Comment: I currently have that but I would like to achieve this effect as the border in the picture shown https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBe07.png

Comment: Why do you have */ at the end of some CSS lines?

Comment: Sorry about that honest mistake I was trying to comment out some of the css to see how it would look.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7hdrhs2r/4/ like this?

Comment: Yea something like that but I would like that blue background at the back of it and not stretched across the page.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7hdrhs2r/5/

Comment: Less code: https://jsfiddle.net/7hdrhs2r/7/

Comment: Yes that is the ideal solution I was looking for thank you.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#picturebox img {
  border: solid 3px red;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7hdrhs2r/7/)

> **Note**: to comment out CSS, do this:

```
/* code */
```

> Works with multiline comments as well:

```
/* code
code */
```